# Database field to describe if data should be high or low?

Tags: mysql, database, breadcrumbs, saas, baker-framework

So I'm making a web app for tracking various data for a bakery. Initially I want to track 3 different key performance indicators:

1. Baguettes sold per day
2. Complaints per day
3. Tips per day

However, I want to make an extensible system so rather than hard-code this I am looking to make a table where I can store my different KPIs. I have a table where I am defining my key performance indicators for the bakery, including fields such as:

- KPI name e.g. "baguettes sold"
- KPI unit e.g. "units" (for baguettes sold), "USD" (for "tips per day")
- KPI...order?

This last field has me a bit confused - I want to basically describe if the KPI should be a high value (the more baguettes sold per day, the better) or a low value (the fewer complaints per day, the better).

Is there a terminology for such a thing, or an accepted best practice of how to define and store such a value? Thanks!

Comment: Is that field really necessary? Are the end users going to be honestly confused as to whether a high amount of sales or a high amount of complaints is a good or a bad thing?

Comment: Why not to call it just IsHigherBetter ? And make it boolean.

Comment: @dfundako further on in development I will add reporting abilities, including email digests etc, and so its important to be able to flag up KPIs that are performing poorly, which is why I need to be able to define which ones are doing poorly and which are doing great. However I'm under NDA from the bakery so i can't say much more.

Comment: @koryakinp sounds good to me, but I just wanted to ask if I was missing something, such as if there is a terminology for such a thing, or an accepted best practice of how to define and store such a value.